# arising [Int -> Int] instead of [Int] from `map`

Tags: haskell, lambda

I trying to pass two composite lambdas to `map`, such like

```hs
f::[Int]
f = map ((\_ a->2*a) . (\_ a->a^2)) [1..10]
```

resulting in

```
test.hs:8:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Integer -> Integer’ with ‘Int’
      Expected type: [Int]
        Actual type: [Integer -> Integer]
    • In the expression:
        map ((\ _ a -> a + 1) . (\ _ a -> a - 1)) [1 .. 5]
      In an equation for ‘f’:
          f = map ((\ _ a -> 2*a) . (\ _ a -> a^2)) [1 .. 5]
  |
8 | f = map ((\_ a->a+1) . (\_ a->a-1)) [1..5]
```

Comment: What is the `_` in `\_ a ->` doing here?

Comment: `(\_ a->2*a) . (\_ a->a^2)` looks wrong here, since it is equivalent to `\x -> ((\_ a->2*a) . (\_ a->a^2)) x` hence to `\x -> (\_ a->2*a) ((\_ a->a^2)) x)` hence to `\x -> \ a->2*a` hence to `\_ a->2*a`. I can't believe this was the intended function, given the additional complexity of the original code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that `map` has type

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

In your case that argument has type

```
((\_ a->2*a) . (\_ a->a^2)) :: Num b => a -> b -> b
```

If we map this function over a list we get a type like

```
[b -> b]
```

(In your case the list `[1..10]` is assumed to be of type `[Integer]` hence why you get the `Actual type: [Integer -> Integer]`.)

But in the signature of the function `f` says it should be of type `[Int]` so something is going wrong here.
My guess is that you mistakenly added a *second argument* `_` to your lambdas, so I think you actually wanted to write

```
f = map ((\a->2*a) . (\a->a^2)) [1..10]
```

Note that you can shorten this - using operator sections - to

```
f = map ((2*) . (^2)) [1..10]
```